# Get all screenshots in one location with PHPUnit/Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I'm using PHPUnit to run my Selenium tests.  I'm using captureScreenshotOnFailure to get screenshots when my assertions fail.

I run tests on a Linux box, a Mac and a Windows box.  The tests are all run from the Linux (Ubuntu) box.

I would like to get all of the failure screenshots in one location.  Everything that I've read, just says that the screenshots are put on the host computer (if the test fails in IE on the Windows box, the screenshots have to be saved on the Windows box).
Does anyone have any great ideas on how I could make my screenshots all "end up" on the Linux box, regardless of where they occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a shared drive/folder (e.g. SMB or WebDAV) on linux and mount this on the other computers, so PHPUnit saves the screenshots to this drive.

Comment: Nice thought. It looks like a shared folder, with this change to phpunit-selenium (https://github.com/nfabre/phpunit-selenium/) I'll be able to give a different location to each machine running the tests.